# Do you need an instance of statsd running per web node?

Tags: statsd

Is the idea that each web server has an instance of statsd running and then you push those to something like collectrd?

I understand that the metric calls are udp so they are very light, but this means you may be making 3-5 calls to statsd per page and I am wondering if that would cause issues at some point?

Or is udp so fast that you can make thousands of calls per second and it won't be an issue because it is fire and forget type of request.

Answer (score 2):

For **robustness'** sake I would actually recommend to have 1 statsd instance per node. It's lightweight enough to not matter when it's only getting one instance's worth of metrics.

If you centralize statsd and that process/box dies, you're completely blind until you stand up another process/box. Not the best situation to be in.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would recommend starting with a single instance, since it's less overhead to manage and to set up. If you're running a StatsD instance on each webserver you have to make sure to send the hostname with your metrics to not override anything on the Graphite side. And you also have to do more work on the Graphite/Dashboard side to make sense of your metrics. In a setup where not all hosts send to a single StatsD instance you have to sum over all hosts to get all login counters, page load timings are by host and you need to do more work to get an overall picture. This all doesn't make it impossible but more complicated to get started. That's why I think starting with a single instance is easier if you don't know for sure you are quickly outgrowing the performance a single box can get you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the idea that each web server has an instance of statsd running and
>   then you push those to something like collectrd?

Statsd is a Collectd replacement. You can have a single statsd instance over the LAN and have all the 'pages' send metrics to it. The next logical step would be visualizing these metrics. You might think of [Graphite](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) here.

> I understand that the metric calls are udp so they are very light, but
>   this means you may be making 3-5 calls to statsd per page and I am
>   wondering if that would cause issues at some point?

i am making 10K calls to a single statsd per minute. The issues can be many- your server may get CPU, memory, network or IO bound. Yes UDP is much, much lighter than TCP. Don't worry about the scale. There's a lot of runway for you out there, as for now.

> Having multiple statsd instances:

It would be a REALLY BAD idea to have multiple statsd clients, unless from scalability standpoint. Later on, changing the configuration will become a headache. Debugging which of the n statsd is/are incorrectly configured will be also difficult. So the 'light weight' overhead is an invitation for non-maintainable architecture. As far as robustness is concerned, there are people doing much much more than your current needs without facing any failures from statsd. As i said, i am doing 10K metrics per minute.